# How do you get the target/origin of errors and error events when using UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR (AS3)?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, error-handling, uncaught-exception

Is it possible to get the target/origin of errors and error events when using UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR ?

I am logging runtime errors of users using a complex flash app and would like to know where things are failing.

The target of the UncaughtErrorEvent is tracing as LoaderInfo (which is, I assume, because it is also kicking out the UncaughtErrorEvent) and the target of the ErrorEvent is null.

```
this.loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, uncaughtErrorHandler);

private function uncaughtErrorHandler(event:UncaughtErrorEvent):void {
  trace("event.target: " + event.target)
  if (event.error is Error){
    var error:Error = event.error as Error;
  }else if (event.error is ErrorEvent){
    var errorEvent:ErrorEvent = event.error as ErrorEvent;
    trace("errorEvent.target: " + errorEvent.target)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me - output the error like this:

`trace( (event.error as Error).getStackTrace() );`

See [Here](http://blog.dannypatterson.com/2011/05/dont-cast-an-uncaughterrorevent-error/)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that you can. The targets are the loaders. I imagine this is due to the way the application and security sandbox work.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/UncaughtErrorEvent.html

Answer (score 0):

As [this article](http://ripeworks.com/tracing-as3-to-chrome/) said, you can retrieve the stack trace from the private error property of the ErrorEvent object. I'm copy-pasting the relevant code block :

```
    private function uncaughtErrorHandler(e:UncaughtErrorEvent):void
    {
        if( e.error is Error)
        {
            var stack:String = Error(e.error).getStackTrace();
            Console.error(Error(e.error).message + ((stack!=null)? "\n"+stack : ""));
        }
        else if( e.error is ErrorEvent)
            Console.error(ErrorEvent(e.error).text);
        else
            Console.error(e.error.toString());
    }
```